# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{\cos x}{x-\pi/2}$ in terms of $(\cos x)'$

Tags: calculus, limits

Calculate $$\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos x}{x-\frac{\pi}{2}}$$ by relating it to a value of $(\cos x)'$.

The answer is available [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/part-a-definition-and-basic-rules/problem-set-1/MIT18_01SC_pset1sol.pdf) (pdf) at 1J-2.

However, I can't seem to make sense of what is actually being done here.

Comment: Will you be able to handle $$\lim_{t-\frac{\pi}{2}\to 0} \, \frac{\cos \left(x+t-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)-\cos (x)}{t-\frac{\pi }{2}}$$

Comment: Yes, that substitution makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying l'Hopital rule, you have

$$
\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\frac{\cos x}{x-\pi/2}=\lim_{x\to\pi/2}(\cos x)'=\left.(\cos x)'\right|_{x=\pi/2}
$$
that in turn becomes
$$\left.(\cos x)'\right|_{x=\pi/2}=\left.(-\sin x)\right|_{x=\pi/2}=-1$$

Comment: Too high-powered. One only needs to go back to how the derivative is defined...

Comment: @J.M. but probably simpler to think of for a beginner.

Comment: I don't know; last time I checked, one is usually taught the definition of the derivative **way before** one is taught l'Hôpital, but I guess you kids do things differently these days...

Comment: l´hopital does, indeed, still come later, I think. Thanks for both answers though!

Answer (score 0):

Use the definition of derivative at a point,

$$ f'(x_0) = \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} \,.$$
In your case $f(x)=\cos(x)$ and $x_0=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** : I think you wanna use the notation $y = x - \frac{\pi}{2}$.